# Is it possible to change the generic type parameter of a Func<T, bool> delegate?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, func, type-parameter

I imagine that the answer to this question is 'no', but here goes anyway.

Basically, I have a `Linq2Sql` data provider with its generated types. I also have business objects whose property names (for the sake of this question) exactly match the property names of their related generated types. The business types are used throughout the application and the generated types are used ONLY for accessing the database - this setup is desirable for a number of reasons, so please don't suggest answers that requires any change in this.

In the UI layer, there are various controls that allow the user to adjust how searches are made, eg. which fields to search for, search terms, etc. Using these controls, I can create a nice `Func<T, bool>` delegate to encapsulate the search conditions/query. The problem that I have is that the `Func` delegate is created with the `T` type parameter being the business object and when it gets passed to the data access layer, I need it to be of the related generated type instead.

So my question is, **is it possible to change the generic type parameter of the Func delegate from the business object type to the related generated type while keeping the same conditions?**

```
eg. can Func<MasterTrack, bool>   =>   Func<DbMasterTrack, bool> when properties match?
```

Please also note that I could just pass all of the user selected search parameters to the data access layer, but there are quite a few of them, so I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: Make interface `IMasterTrack` and use it in `Func`. Your both class must implement `IMasterTrack`. I hope this will work.

Comment: Can you show us what your `MasterTrack` and `DbMasterTrack` objects look like i.e. is there any form of inheritance between them, are they following a shared contract `interface` or abstraction, or are they simply two separate concrete classes that have the exact same property structure?

Comment: As @Maarten says, `Linq2Sql will NOT accept an interface-type in its expression`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe that's possible but you can get away with doing the following:

- Make `DbMasterTrack` implicitly convertible to `MasterTrack`;
- When querying just wrap your `Func<MasterTack,bool>` in a `Func<DbMasterTrack,bool>`.

I also have to note that if you're using `Func<T, bool>` instead of `Expression<Func<T, bool>` that you're not really filtering the result set at the database level, but that may be something that you're already aware of.

Example follows:

```
class MasterTrack
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
class DbMasterTrack
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public static implicit operator MasterTrack(DbMasterTrack @this)
    {
        return new MasterTrack { Id = @this.Id, Name = @this.Name };
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tracks = new List<DbMasterTrack>
        {
            new DbMasterTrack { Id = 1, Name = "T1" },
            new DbMasterTrack { Id = 2, Name = "T2" },
        };

        Func<MasterTrack, bool> query = t => t.Id == 1;

        var result = tracks.Where((Func<DbMasterTrack, bool>)(t => query(t)));

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}|{1}", item.Id, item.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the idea behind this solution and am grateful to discover the `implicit operator`, so +1 for that. I have tried to implement your solution (hence the delayed response), but I have fallen at the last hurdle! It all compiles Ok, but at run-time, I got an exception stating 'Method 'MasterTrack op_Implicit(DbMasterTrack)' has no supported translation to SQL'. This looks like a show-stopper to me, but if you can help with this, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: The reason you're seeing that is because `t => query(t)` is considered a `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` and then LINQ2SQL tries to convert it to SQL. If you cast it to `Func<T, bool>`, it should work, but again I have to warn you that you'll not be filtering at the database. If you want to filter at the database you need to use `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` from the beginning and try Maarten approach.

Comment: Ahhhh. Many thanks for pointing out that the Func<T, bool> does its filtering locally, which of course makes a big difference. I will have to use the generic `Expression` class instead. Many thanks all the same and I'm sure I'll make use of the `implicit` stuff again.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things

1. Linq2Sql can also use an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` instead of a `Func<T, bool>`.
2. It is not possible to **change** the type of a `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`
3. Is is possible to copy/re-create a `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` where you replace type T with another type.
4. Linq2Sql will **NOT** accept an interface-type in its expression. So if you think about creating interfaces to 'abstract' the actual type, that will not work.

Now, to create an `Expression<Func<T2, bool>>` from an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` I once created the following code. It is not 'complete', as in not all possible paths in an expression are supported. But the basic and/or combinations where you check properties for values (< > = != or combinaties) were working fine then.

Using this code you can do:

```
Expression<Func<MasterTrack, bool>> criteria = m => m.Id == 1;
Expression<Func<DbMasterTrack, bool>> dbCriteria = ExpressionRewriter.CastParam<MasterTrack, DbMasterTrack>(criteria);
```

Here we go.

```
public static class ExpressionRewriter {
    /// <summary>
    /// Casts the param of an expression.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TIn">The type of the in.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TOut">The type of the out.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="inExpr">The in expr.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Expression<Func<TOut, bool>> CastParam<TIn, TOut>(Expression<Func<TIn, bool>> inExpr) {
        if (inExpr.NodeType == ExpressionType.Lambda &&
            inExpr.Parameters.Count > 0) {

            var inP = inExpr.Parameters[0];
            var outP = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TOut), inP.Name);

            var outBody = Rewrite<TIn, TOut>(
                inExpr.Body,
                expr => (expr is ParameterExpression) ? outP : expr
            );
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<TOut, bool>>(
                    outBody,
                    new ParameterExpression[] { outP });
        } else {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Rewrites the specified expression.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TIn">The type of the in.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TOut">The type of the out.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="exp">The exp.</param>
    /// <param name="c">The c.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static Expression Rewrite<TIn, TOut>(Expression exp, Func<Expression, Expression> c) {
        Expression clone = null;
        var be = exp as BinaryExpression;
        switch (exp.NodeType) {
            case ExpressionType.AndAlso:
                clone = Expression.AndAlso(Rewrite<TIn, TOut>(be.Left, c), Rewrite<TIn, TOut>(be.Right, c), be.Method);
                break;
            case ExpressionType.OrElse:
                clone = Expression.OrElse(Rewrite<TIn, TOut>(be.Left, c), Rewrite<TIn, TOut>(be.Right, c), be.Method);
                break;
            case ExpressionType.Equal:
                clone = Expression.Equal(Rewrite<TIn, TOut>(be.Left, c), Rewrite<TIn, TOut>(be.Right, c), be.IsLiftedToNull, be.Method);
                break;
            case ExpressionType.GreaterThan:
                clone = Expression.GreaterThan(Rewrite<TIn, TOut>(be.Left, c), Rewrite<TIn, TOut>(be.Right, c), be.IsLiftedToNull, be.Method);
                break;
            case ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual:
                clone = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(Rewrite<TIn, TOut>(be.Left, c), Rewrite<TIn, TOut>(be.Right, c), be.IsLiftedToNull, be.Method);
                break;
            case ExpressionType.LessThan:
                clone = Expression.LessThan(Rewrite<TIn, TOut>(be.Left, c), Rewrite<TIn, TOut>(be.Right, c), be.IsLiftedToNull, be.Method);
                break;
            case ExpressionType.LessThanOrEqual:
                clone = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(Rewrite<TIn, TOut>(be.Left, c), Rewrite<TIn, TOut>(be.Right, c), be.IsLiftedToNull, be.Method);
                break;
            case ExpressionType.NotEqual:
                clone = Expression.NotEqual(Rewrite<TIn, TOut>(be.Left, c), Rewrite<TIn, TOut>(be.Right, c), be.IsLiftedToNull, be.Method);
                break;
            case ExpressionType.Not:
                var ue = exp as UnaryExpression;
                clone = Expression.Not(Rewrite<TIn, TOut>(ue.Operand, c));
                break;
            case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
                var me = exp as MemberExpression;

                MemberInfo newMember = me.Member;
                Type newType = newMember.DeclaringType;
                if (newType == typeof(TIn)) {
                    newType = typeof(TOut);
                    MemberInfo[] members = newType.GetMember(me.Member.Name);
                    if (members.Length == 1) {
                        newMember = members[0];
                    } else {
                        throw new NotSupportedException();
                    }
                }
                clone = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Rewrite<TIn, TOut>(me.Expression, c), newMember);
                break;
            case ExpressionType.Constant:
                var ce = exp as ConstantExpression;
                clone = Expression.Constant(ce.Value);
                break;
            case ExpressionType.Parameter:
                var pe = exp as ParameterExpression;
                Type peNewType = pe.Type;
                if (peNewType == typeof(TIn)) {
                    peNewType = typeof(TOut);
                }
                clone = Expression.Parameter(peNewType, pe.Name);
                break;
            case ExpressionType.Call:
                MethodCallExpression mce = exp as MethodCallExpression;
                if (mce.Arguments != null && mce.Arguments.Count > 0) {
                    List<Expression> expressionList = new List<Expression>();
                    foreach (Expression expression in mce.Arguments) {
                        expressionList.Add(Rewrite<TIn, TOut>(expression, c));
                    }
                    clone = Expression.Call(Rewrite<TIn, TOut>(mce.Object, c), mce.Method, expressionList.ToArray());
                } else {
                    clone = Expression.Call(Rewrite<TIn, TOut>(mce.Object, c), mce.Method);
                }
                break;
            case ExpressionType.Invoke:
                InvocationExpression ie = exp as InvocationExpression;
                List<Expression> arguments = new List<Expression>();
                foreach (Expression expression in ie.Arguments) {
                    arguments.Add(Rewrite<TIn, TOut>(expression, c));
                }
                clone = Rewrite<TIn, TOut>(ie.Expression, c);
                //clone = Expression.Invoke(Rewrite<TIn, TOut>(ie.Expression, c), arguments);
                break;
            case ExpressionType.Convert:
                var ue2 = exp as UnaryExpression;
                //clone = Expression.Not(Rewrite<TIn, TOut>(ue2.Operand, c));
                clone = Expression.Convert(ue2.Operand, ue2.Type, ue2.Method);
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException(exp.NodeType.ToString());
        }
        return c(clone);
    }
}
```

Comment: Again, I like this solution, so +1 for that... it is after all, the closest answer to my question. Having implemented @Joao Angelo's solution first, I am going to try to get it all working correctly, but if that fails, I'll come back to this. Many thanks.

Comment: After trying your solution, I'm afraid to say that it didn't work either. I got an exception because there is no `Case` for `ExpressionType.Lambda` in your Rewrite method.

Comment: Did you change your type to Expression<Func<MasterTrack, bool>> ? And what does your expression consist of?

Comment: Yes, I did. I'm now using the excellent `PredicateBuilder` from http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx. Inside, it just contains statements like this (but 'and'ed for different properties): `m => m.Title.Contains(SearchTerm)`.